# Removing words/characters from string in dataframe cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that contains street intersections

```
|          Locations           |
--------------------------------
|W Madison Ave & S Randall Blvd|
|N Clemson St & E Tower Ave    |
|E Thompson St & S Garfield Ln |
```

I'd like to remove the directional characters (N, S, E, W) as well as the suffixes of the streets (Blvd, St, Ave, etc...) so that my output looks like this

```
|     Locations     |
---------------------
|Madison & Randall  |
|Clemson & Tower    |
|Thompson & Garfield|
```

I can't do a `str.replace()` because it would be removing characters from the words I need to stay. I tried using `lstrip()` and `rstrip()` but that wouldn't fix the characters I'd like removed from the middle of the string.

I also tried experimenting with `Series.apply()`

```
banned = ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'Ave', 'Blvd', 'St', 'Ln']
df["Locations"].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in banned])
```

But this essentially does a `str.replace()` and places everything in a list in the dataframe instead.

Comment: Your apply would work if `df.col.apply(lambda r: ' '.join(k for k in r.split() if not np.isin(k, banned)))`

Comment: Do all your entries follow the exact same pattern? Because then it might be an easier option to just display the second and the sixth string, after splitting it on spaces

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are close - you can split values first and then `join`:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in banned])
df["Locations"] = df["Locations"].apply(f)
```

Or `list comprehension`:

```
df["Locations"] = [' '.join([item for item in x.split() 
                  if item not in banned]) 
                  for x in df["Locations"]]


print (df)
             Locations
0    Madison & Randall
1      Clemson & Tower
2  Thompson & Garfield
```

Comment: Do you know where I might put a `.lower()` in there to cover all my bases? The data contains some of the banned words in uppercase.

Comment: @ATCH_torn - Then use `banned1 = [a.lower() for a in banned]
f = lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item.lower() not in banned1])`

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you this solved a problem I had.

However, I cannot figure out how the logic works of the function. 
Could you explain how the function works?

Comment: @SebastiantenBerge - For each value of Series is call list comprehension - there is splitted values by whitespace, filtered values for no in `banned` and last join back by space.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `replace` as you mentioned

```
df.replace(dict(zip(banned,['']*len(banned))),regex=True)
Out[54]: 
                      Locations           
0           Madison  &  Randall 
1            Clemson t &  Tower     
2        Thompson t &  Garfield
```

Comment: You need them in order from largest string to smallest. `df.Locations.str.replace(f"\s*({'|'.join(sorted(banned, key=len, reverse=True))})\s*", ' ').str.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to removing words you don't want, you can choose to select the words that you do want. As your example rows follow the same pattern, it looks like you want to select the 2nd and 6th word and use them to make the new name of the location. This would look something like this:

```
df['new_location'] = ''

for i,location in enumerate(df.Locations):
        df.new_location.iloc[i] = location.split(' ')[1] +' & ' +location.split(' ')[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `s` is the following `Series`:

```
0    |          Locations           |
1    --------------------------------
2    |W Madison Ave & S Randall Blvd|
3    |N Clemson St & E Tower Ave    |
4    |E Thompson St & S Garfield Ln |
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

You can use the following regular expression

```
s.str.replace('(?:E|W|N|St?|Blvd|Ave|Ln)', '')
```

to get

```
0    |          Locations           |
1    --------------------------------
2             | Madison  &  Randall |
3           | Clemson  &  Tower     |
4          | Thompson  &  Garfield  |
Name: 0, dtype: object
```